# adding Ethereum repository fails (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: apt, ethereum

I am running the following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
```

The error message is:

```
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/hpttps could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-hpttps installed?
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is a strange typo - it says `hpttps` instead of `https` - wonder why that is?

Comment: "hpttps" seems strange indeed. "http" and "https" exists in that directory, but not "hpttps". Any idea, why my error messages somehow references to "hpttps"?

Comment: Yes, I have found now the reason. I previously added another repository and altered the coresponding file from "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" and made a type with "hpttps" instead of "https". This resulted in blocking another repository (Ethereum repository) to be added. I corrected the file and I could finally add this repository.